# minikube - x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, ssl, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am using `minikube` and `kubectl` to create an `RC` for `mongo`. And I am using the company's VPN.

Created the `RC` via `kubectl create -f ./rc/mongo-rc.yaml` command.

Got below kubernetes events when using `kubectl describe pod mongo-5zttk` command:

```sh
...
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  7m18s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/mongo-5zttk to minikube
  Normal   Pulling    5m42s (x4 over 7m17s)  kubelet, minikube  Pulling image "mongo"
  Warning  Failed     5m40s (x4 over 7m15s)  kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull image "mongo": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/mongo/manifests/latest: Get https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fmongo%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
  Warning  Failed     5m40s (x4 over 7m15s)  kubelet, minikube  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    5m29s (x6 over 7m15s)  kubelet, minikube  Back-off pulling image "mongo"
  Warning  Failed     2m8s (x21 over 7m15s)  kubelet, minikube  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

When I try to use `curl` to access the URL:

```sh
⚡  curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/mongo/manifests/latest
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":[{"Type":"repository","Class":"","Name":"library/mongo","Action":"pull"}]}]}
```

I can pull the `mongo:latest` image from the docker hub registry successfully.

```sh
⚡  docker pull mongo:latest
latest: Pulling from library/mongo
Digest: sha256:efc408845bc917d0b7fd97a8590e9c8d3c314f58cee651bd3030c9cf2ce9032d
Status: Image is up to date for mongo:latest
docker.io/library/mongo:latest
```

Environment information:

- minikube version: v1.14.1
- kubectl

  - Client Version: v1.18.8
  - Server Version: v1.19.2
- OS: macOS 10.13.6

I have read the doc: [vpn_and_proxy/#x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/vpn_and_proxy/#x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority). The solution is to ask the IT department for the appropriate PEM file. Is there any solution if I can't get the PEM file? Such as use some command flag: `--skip-verify-cert`?

**UPDATE:**

`mongo-rc.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata: 
  name: mongo
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    app: mongo
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec: 
      containers: 
      - name: mongo
        image: mongo
        ports: 
        - containerPort: 27017
        env: 
        - name: MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: "123456"
```

Comment: can you provide the containerspec section where you are mentioning image details it has to use ?

Comment: @confusedgenius Done. I included the k8s RC resource YAML file.

Comment: I tried the same yaml on my setup and it worked fine and i looked at TLS Certificates of https://registry-1.docker.io and they are properly signed and that might be the reason why docker pull is working fine for you as well .so i think error message is misdirecting may it is complaining about your kubernetes certificates.can you confirm if you are getting this error messages for any other images as well ?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the `--insecure-registry` flag, but you might have to recreate your minikube cluster for it to work.

```
minikube start --insecure-registry="registry-1.docker.io"
```

Comment: I deleted my cluster using `minikube delete --all --purge` command. After that, recreated my minikube cluster using the command you provided. Still got the same issue.

Comment: Add the port to the command:

❌  Exiting due to MK_USAGE: Sorry, the address provided with the --insecure-registry flag is invalid: registry-1.docker.io. Expected formtas are: <ip>:<port>, <hostname>:<port> or <network>/<netmask>

Like: minikube start --insecure-registry="registry-1.docker.io:443"

Comment: the argument `--insecure-registry` is unknown (MK v1.27.1)

Not among `minikube -v` propositions neither.

Comment: --insecure-registry=[]:
 Insecure Docker registries to pass to the Docker daemon.  The default service CIDR range will automatically be
 added.

Found at `minikube start --help`

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was while pulling the `"hello-world"` image from the docker registry, with the following error:

```
response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Using `openssl`, get the certificate(s).

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -connect registry-1.docker.io:443
```

Save all of the certificates from the openssl output in individual `.crt` files.

Copy all the certificates to `~/.minikube/certs`.

After copying:

- minikube delete
- restart docker
- restart minikube

See this [article](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/vpn_and_proxy/#x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Tried a lot of stuff, only one working for me is :

1. enter MK container in shell, create a file (for ex /root/docker.sh) with following entries :

```
update-ca-certificates --fresh
openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -connect k8s.gcr.io:443 < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -outform PEM | tee ~/k8s.gcr.io.crt
openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -connect registry-1.docker.io:443 < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -outform PEM | tee ~/registry-1.docker.io.crt
openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -connect auth.docker.io:443 < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -outform PEM | tee ~/auth.docker.io.crt
cp ~/k8s.gcr.io.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
cp ~/registry-1.docker.io.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
cp ~/auth.docker.io.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
update-ca-certificates
# service docker restart
```

2. Execute it once, or add the execution safely along with docker start (/etc/init.d/docker)

```
...
case "$1" in
        start)
                # <add-following-line>
                /root/./docker.sh
                # </add-following-line>
                check_init
                fail_unless_root
                cgroupfs_mount
                ..
```

Answer (score 0):

For helm version 3.13.1
you may start your minikube with below

```
 minikube start --insecure-registry="registry.k8s.io"
```